# what to use as asp.net membership backend ? RavenDB or SqlServer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership, ravendb

I have a project in which most of data are planned to be saved in RavenDB . the problem is membership . I couldn't find any ( trusted , supported by a team , popular ) membership provider in RavenDB ,and I don't want to create a custom one ( I'm not sure I can create one as perfect as asp.net's default ) . So I think the only way is to use a sql server database Alongside RavenDB to support membership operations .

So 
is there any membership provider for ravenDB that I've missed ?

I don't feel comfortable with this solution (using 2 databases ) .I appreciate any advice or solution .

Comment: If you need to reference the same user objects from other RavenDB data then I'd definitely go RavenDB. It should be reasonably easy to write a membership provider for it, and [(an old version of) the SqlMembershipProvider source was published](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx) that you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there any membership provider for ravenDB that I've missed ?

There's this one on github:

https://github.com/martijnboland/RavenDBMembership

Comment: Thank you , I checked it , but it's not what I'm looking for ( trusted , supported by a team , popular ) . as it's writer has said " it was time for an experiment and took Raven DB to create an ASP.NET membership provider " .

Comment: Well it's got fifteen forks on github so there must be a small community of users for it, plus half a dozen of them have committed fixes back so it seems reasonable to assume it is being used in production somewhere. I don't think you're going to find a more popular one. Your best bet then would be to ask Hibernating Rhinos if they have one themselves, and if not whether they'd consider adopting and supporting this one for you: they use github for all their stuff themselves and I know one of their guys who has plenty of ASP.NET knowledge etc. (assuming you pay them already, that is!)

Comment: I'll take it as my last bullet .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is neccessarily the best option...

But as an alternative view point you could perhaps try an XML based membership provider. I have used one a few years back for a very small bespoke CMS that didn't have a database backend.

It's probably not suitable for you, as I'm guessing on of the reasons for chosing RavenDB is for it's scalability etc i.e. your perhaps not building a small site - but worth a mention just in case.

Comment: thank you , actually I'm using RavenDB because of it's schema free nature . I can create a custom provider but I'm trying to find something as comprehensive as Asp.net membership Sqlprovider to save my time and reduce my security concerns

Comment: Cool, an xml membership provider might be the way to go - though it's been a long time since I've used them... I think I may of used one downloaded from the asp.net site - but I can't find it anymore. Another alternative could be Sql Compact using ASP.net universal providers: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx